# Jquery PrettyPhoto removing #prettyphoto from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I use version 3.1.4 of prettyphoto. (http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/). I want to remove "#prettyphoto[iframe]/number/" from URL. I've set deeplinking:false but this don't help. I've understood that it might be the problem from these functions:

```
function getHashtag(){url=location.href;hashtag=(url.indexOf('#prettyPhoto')!==-1)?decodeURI(url.substring(url.indexOf('#prettyPhoto')+1,url.length)):false;return hashtag;};
function setHashtag(){if(typeof theRel=='undefined')return;location.hash=theRel+'/'+rel_index+'/';};
function clearHashtag(){if(location.href.indexOf('#prettyPhoto')!==-1)location.hash="prettyPhoto";}
```

Any idea?

Comment: +1. The appending of #prettyphoto to URLs is #prettyAnnoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) This worked for me:

```
function clearHashtag(){
    if(location.href.indexOf('#prettyPhoto')!==-1)
        location.hash="";
}
```

This code is at the bottom of jquery.prettyPhoto.js

b) There is another way, like setting: **deeplinking: false** at the beginning of jquery.prettyPhoto.js.

I mean here:

```
(function($){$.prettyPhoto={version:'3.1.4'};$.fn.prettyPhoto=function(pp_settings){pp_settings=jQuery.extend({.. deeplinking: false; ...}
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: please give me more details, Manindra

Comment: i have done all this mention above by you but i m not able to get rid of that #prettyphoto tag from url.i m also using the version 3.1.4.

Comment: Please use pastebin or something like that and show me your code, I'll try to help you by editing it.

Answer (score 10):

This is my code and it worked for me:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        social_tools:false,
        deeplinking:false});
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

3.1.5 version will work

```
(function($){$.prettyPhoto={version:'3.1.5'};
$.fn.prettyPhoto=function(pp_settings){pp_settings=jQuery.extend(
{.. deeplinking: false; ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
(function($) {
    console.log('check');

    $.prettyPhoto = {
        version : '3.1.5'
    };

    $.fn.prettyPhoto = function(pp_settings) {
        pp_settings = $.extend({
            deeplinking : false
        });
    };

    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

})(jQuery);
```